# Combining Linq and SQL query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

I have:

1. Simple search engine which is a dynamically built sql query. From this query I'm receiving product Id and Points (search rank). This query is based on search configuration. User can chose which fields he want to search and etc.
2. IQueryable where are my products with filters applied and some additional data joined.

What I want to do:

Join results from Sql Query with IQueryable so I will have my products that fulfill search conditions and other filters and have Points joined. I need to get my results as IQuryable

I have tried to rewrite this search engine to linq but I ended up with really huge and slow queries.

I've tried to fire up my sql query and get it as IQueryable and then join it to my IQueryable. That didn't worked out got some error.

Any tips?

EDIT:
Sample SQL Search Query;

```
SELECT Id, SUM(Points) AS Points
FROM  (
    SELECT tw_Id Id ,500 AS Points
    from tw__Towar
    Where 
    tw_Nazwa Like '%WA20-800%'
union all
    SELECT tw_Id Id ,2500 AS Points
    from tw__Towar
    Where 
    tw_Nazwa Like '%WA20-800%' 
union all
    SELECT tw_Id Id ,5000 AS Points
    from tw__Towar
    Where 
tw_Symbol Like 'WA20-800 %') sub
group by Id
```

The code gets way more complicated when there are more then one keyword.
I've tried to execute it in way:

```
dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<PointsId>(query).AsQueryable();
```

and then join it to my IQueryable. But it didn't worked.

Comment: Can you add some sample query

Comment: LINQ isn't a substitute for SQL. If you try to covnert a complex SQL query to a LINQ to EF/SQL query, you are doing it *very* wrong. It's also pointless, unless you want to apply extra processing on top of some complex query. Create a view or function to hide the complex query and map it to an entity that represents the result. Then you'll be able to apply *extra* operations on top of the view

Comment: From Niels Hüsken : What does the result of the query look like? Is it big? If not, how about joining the results in memory. Create an enumerable (List, Array or a Dictionary) from each of the results and join them manualy.

Comment: Instead of `LIKE` use `PATINDEX` to find the index of the pattern inside the field, then use `CASE WHEN ` to return the score. That's a single `SELECT` statement

Comment: Also note that SQL Server already has Full Text Search support. In your case though you aren't really doing that

Comment: is there a finite list of things that the user can search on?